# What Port Does Android Use For VPN Connections?

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, vpn

I'm trying to set up a VPN so that I can have a connection to my LAN from my phone (HTC Droid Incredible, Stock ROM, Not rooted) wherever I am.

AFAICT, everything is set up correctly.  The Domain Name resolves correctly, I forwarded the ports required by the how-to I was following, yet I still can't connect.

I have no idea what's wrong or how to get to any debug information.  The only thing I can think of that I haven't verified yet is the port, but I couldn't find a way to select one.

What Port Does Android Use For VPN Connections?

P.S.  I would *really* like to do this without rooting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access to a computer that

1. is on the same Wi-Fi network; and
2. runs Wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org/)

you can probably find out the port that way.

Comment: This will also hopefully let you see What's Really Happening. Sniff phone side, sniff LAN side, compare.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to VPN from your phone to publicly accessible computer that is also part of your LAN, it really doesn't matter what port the VPN client on your phone uses.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so that you need to have to port if you are willing to use a VPN on Android. You simply need to add the server name in the settings which will be given to you by your VPN provider. However, I will advise you to configure the setting again on VPN Android. It will surely work out as one of my friends has also faced such issues while connecting to VPN but he tried the configuration steps and then able to use the VPN service on his Android phone.

Follow these simple steps.

**Add a new VPN connection:**

1. Press the Home icon, press Menu, and tap Settings
2. Tap Wireless & networks
3. Tap VPN settings
4. Tap Add VPN
5. Select the type of VPN to add (PPTP, L2TP, L2TP/IPSec PSK VPN, L2TP/IPsec CRT VPN)
6. Fill in VPN details such as VPN name, VPN server, etc (the required settings will depend on the type of VPN selected and will be provided to you by your VPN Provider or network admin)
7. Click Save or Done.

**Connecting to the VPN:**

1. Press Home icon, press Menu, and tap Settings
2. Tap Wireless & networks
3. Tap VPN settings.
4. The VPN connections you have added are now listed.
5. Tap the VPN you wish to connect to.
6. A dialog box will open asking for your credentials, enter them and touch connect

Answer (score 2):

Here are the ports used by VPNs

**PPTP**

```
To allow PPTP tunnel maintenance traffic, open TCP 1723.
To allow PPTP tunneled data to pass through router, open Protocol ID 47.
```

**L2TP over IPSec**

```
To allow Internet Key Exchange (IKE), open UDP 500.
To allow IPSec Network Address Translation (NAT-T) open UDP 5500.
To allow L2TP traffic, open UDP 1701.
```